# How to resolve Tomcat issue on local machine

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting this error while running Tomcat 8 locally on my machine. I don't know what the issue is however -

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/bin/catalina.sh run
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
[2020-11-25 06:21:30,990] Artifact Server:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.38
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 10 2020 08:20:30 UTC
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.38.0
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.15.6
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           13.0.1+9
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.773 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/archi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_Server
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.774 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/archi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_Server/conf/logging.properties
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/Users/archi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_Server/jmxremote.password
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/archi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_Server/jmxremote.access
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/archi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.3/tomcat/Unnamed_Server
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/temp
25-Nov-2020 18:21:31.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/archi/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:32.046 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:32.088 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [489] milliseconds
25-Nov-2020 18:21:32.131 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:32.131 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:32.141 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:32.150 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [61] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2020-11-25 06:21:32,629] Artifact Server:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
25-Nov-2020 18:21:33.241 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [manageApp]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Server_war_exploded]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3062)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2249)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:987)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        ... 56 more
25-Nov-2020 18:21:33.243 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [createStandardContext]
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method [manageApp]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Server_war_exploded]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3062)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2249)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:987)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        ... 56 more
[2020-11-25 06:21:33,261] Artifact Server:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.149 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/webapps/manager]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.276 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/webapps/manager] has finished in [126] ms
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/bin/catalina.sh stop
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.837 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.847 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.860 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Nov-2020 18:21:42.894 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Disconnected from server
```

Comment: After formatting for readability, you'll see that the issue is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException`.  Is this dependency included in your `pom.xml` and included in the deployment?

Comment: yes, I have it in my pom file

Comment: but I don't know how to add it to lib folder under Project Structure -> Artifacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue - it was a simple error. I forgot to include the maven dependency for aws in my lib folder under Project Structure -> Artifacts